# Regex with avoidation of markdown

Tags: javascript, php, regex, laravel

Pattern is : **/(?:https?://)?(?:[^.]+.)?momento360.com/e/(.*)?/i**

This regex pattern returns the remaining part of the URL after the website.

```
[click here](https://momento360.com/e/uc/1478291a8dd94a8198339f1ffe4b97be?utm_campaign=embed&utm_source=other&size=medium)


https://momento360.com/e/u/a9b53aa8f8b0403ba7a4e18243aabc66


https://momento360.com/e/uc/1478291a8dd94a8198339f1ffe4b97be?upload-key=e84e1fb3567546a885a2a223bde6ef32
```

But now I want to ignore the string that is in `[click here](...)` Markdown

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew. Thank you. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\[click here]\(http[^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^.]+\.)?momento360\.com\/e\/(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TKYfBY/2).

Here,

- `\[click here]\(http[^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches `[click here](...)` substring and skips this match, starting the search for a new match at the location where the failure occurred
- `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^.]+\.)?momento360\.com\/e\/(.*)` - matches an optional `http://` or `https://`, then matches an optional sequence of any 1+ chars other than a dot and then a dot, then `momento360.com/e/` string and then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If all Urls you want to scape are in `()` and others not, you can use this:

```
[^(]https?:?(?:[^.]+.)?momento360.com/e/(.*)?
```